# Command to list all sourced files in TCL

Tags: shell, tcl

Is there a command to list down all sourced files in TCL ?

Eg - I source `a.tcl`, `b.tcl`, `c.tcl` in `test.tcl` file. Is there a TCL command to view the sourced files ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, but you can override the `source` command itself to keep track of the `source`'d files somewhere, like this:

```
rename source __real_source
proc source args {
    global sourced
    lappend sourced $args
    uplevel 1 [linsert $args 0 __real_source]
}
```

**Update:** expanding on the Donal's comment regarding the fragility of the `source` command there's how one could setup an execution trace:

```
proc register_sourced {cmd args} {
  global sourced
  lappend sourced [lindex $cmd end]
}
trace add execution source leave register_sourced
```

Comment: Shouldn't you execute `__real_source` in your `uplevel` command?

Comment: With 8.6, I'd use: `proc source args {lappend ::sourced [lindex $args end];tailcall __real_source {*}$args}`

Comment: Thinking about it, that code will break package loading. It's _vital_ that the current stack frame of the (real) `source` be the “current” one; the package mechanism uses that extensively. It also had the problem that `linsert` doesn't modify variables. Fixed in your code…

Comment: @DonalFellows, then how about putting an ["execution enter" trace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/trace.htm#M10) on the `source` command? Would it work?

Comment: Yes, that would do it. Hadn't thought of that. :-)